# Are web service recommendations off-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

[Online storage service with 15GB that works well on Linux](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/155/what-is-a-good-alternative-to-google-drive)

In my opinion, this is not off-topic, as it specifically requests for service with Linux (software) support.

---

[Self-hosted collaborative real-time editor](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/146/self-hosted-collaborative-real-time-editor)

Is closer to web service, but still asks for software to be installed.

---

Is for example "What is a good blogging service with this list of requirements" on-topic, or off-topic question?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I don't see why web services would be off-topic.

This is a software recommendation site. Whether the software runs on your phone, on your laptop, on your home server, on your rented cloud instance, on your company server or on someone else's servers doesn't change the on-topicness of the question.

Hosting, however, is off-topic. For a web service:

- “**which software shall I run on the server?**” is on-topic, but
- “whose server shall I run it on?” is off-topic.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree, as long as the questions are narrowly scoped, and answers favor depth over breadth. I think we have enough challenges without worrying about what qualifies as 'software' where the distinction is trivial in the context of our scope :)

Comment: @TimPost There's a lot of scope for making mistakes here. We can at least avoid the mistakes that [su] makes!

Comment: @Gilles can you please explicit your comment about SU? If we are to avoid falling in the same trap, we ough to know the trap.

Comment: @VicAche SU has a peculiar way of defining its topic. Questions have to be about computer hardware or computer software that runs on your machine; interacting with a remote computer is off-topic (except when it isn't). “Computer” includes all PCs and all Macs but not tablets or PDAs/smartphones (except maybe tablets if they're running Windows); also includes peripherals, home routers and some interface-less computers such as Raspberry Pis. There are other exceptions such as running OSX in a VM (off-topic because Apple doesn't like it). I've never been able to figure it out.

Comment: This makes it pretty hard to draw a line, though. Example: [Hosted mass mail system with API](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/14203/185). Though the *subject* asks for a "system", the question is basically for a provider ("we are looking to integrate with a hosted system" / "any recommendations to other providers?"). So what makes the difference here? Am I getting that wrong (or don't grasp the idea)? Any clear definition available?

Comment: @Izzy The distinction I make is that the software is on-topic, the hosting is off-topic. As a community, we've had a lot of confusion in meta discussions as to what “web service” means (including a debate on tags which hasn't been fully sorted out). I've tried to clarify my answer here.

Comment: Thanks, Gilles! Aggreed with that. So "mixed questions" (asking for a provider with a fitting software package, like in the example I've linked) would count as...? Since basically, asking for a web-hoster for your pages would also be asking for an Apache/Nginx/... running ;)

Comment: @Gilles, I'm having trouble understanding your last paragraph (and I don't think I'm alone). Do you mind editing / clarifying it?

Comment: @Pacerier Edited, is it clearer now?

Comment: @Gilles, Thanks for the update, btw regarding *"which software shall I run on the server?"*, whose server is this "the server" referring to?

Comment: @Gilles as expected, I'm still getting confused about which "service" is off-topic and which not. OK, [hosting questions](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/675/185) are off-topic. So are [website recommendations](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/80273/website-recommendation). But according to your definition, e.g. [Cloud streaming service](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/27983/185) would be on-topic. To me, that's no software – but rather a "temporary hosting". Though, I cannot close that as the definition here defines it as on-topic. Isn't it "who's server" here?

Comment: @Gilles maybe a few clear examples for your two items would help clarifying. Could you please add some (links are not strictly required I think, but straight examples. E.g. in which category does "I need to stream some videos for a training session" belong? Is that hosting ("who's server")? What about above mentioned "mass mail system with API"?