# Including cloud-based services for software recommendations?

Tags: discussion, scope

I asked this question [Free SaaS machine learning that exports to PMML, with bayes, random forest, NN, SVM, and decision trees](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/31516/what-are-the-free-cloud-based-machine-learning-service) but it was put on hold as off topic.

My question is, in this age of high speed internet where software is migrating as a cloud-based services (e.g. Photoshop, Microsoft Office), should we consider or not cloud-based services as software?

Comment: Related: [Are web service recommendations off-topic?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/44/60) · [Are web API recommendations on-topic?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/716/60)

Comment: Download good old software and it will at least live as long as you have installed in on your PC. Forget the cloud. A service may be gone without notification, leaving you with nothing the next morning. Or maybe it's just your telecom provider, down for two days. I do not depend on the cloud yet and I don't feel I am missing something.

Answer (score 10):

In my opinion, it makes sense that cloud-based software (SaaS) recommendations be on-topic on this Stack Exchange website.

Comment: I'm always lost when it comes to tell the two apart in that area: when is it on- and when off-topic? Where does SaaS start and "plain hosting" end? Is e.g. asking for a "service like Dropbox" asking for a hosting provider for your stuff (off-topic) – or is it SaaS as you can access the files via an API? I was e.g. tempted to close [A web storage site with direct file link](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/31562/185) as it (explicitly!) asks for hosting. But I'm meanwhile completely confused on the topic. A hoster provides a machine running an OS. Isn't that SaaS as well then?

Comment: @Izzy yes there is some gray area between hosting and SaaS. Personally, I would tend to be lenient on it. Unsure how to define an objective boundary here.

Comment: Well, then someone shed a light please. To me know it seems all those questions are either on-topic or grey then.

Answer (score 2):

I'm one of the people who closevoted, and I'm an ex-mod so I happen to have my (rather scanty) notes from when I was a mod handy. And well, [the community seems to think not](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/675/are-hosting-recommendation-requests-on-topic).

There's multiple highly upvoted answers that hint at the same thing but essentially, a question asking for a *tool* can get an answer that's a service, and asking for a service is right out.

In addition, you're asking a *broad* question *polling* for answers *in order to get a list*. While there's some detail over what you need (no cost, supports multiple machine learning models), its kinda hard to see.

It's just not a good fit IMO.

Comment: Is the link you provide relevant? It seems to be about hosting recommendations, while this question pertains to SaaS I believe, given the example the OP referred to.

Comment: IMO hosting is SAAS, essentially. If not unor's links are still relevant I suppose. The point on polling is acceptable tho, no?

Comment: Yes I agree with the point on polling. Regarding SaaS, I would tend to say SaaS = software running on the cloud, the user don't have access to the binaries, vs hosting = the user wants to put some files on the cloud.

Answer (score 0):

How about this way to tell apart on-topic and off-topic SaaS questions:

Criteria: Is the web application software required to build such a SaaS service available off-the-shelf (commercially or freely) for on-premise installation?

Yes -> [Hosting question](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/675/are-hosting-recommendation-requests-on-topic), off-topic

No -> [Webapp question](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44/are-web-service-recommendations-off-topic), on-topic

Applied to the case of the SaaS machine learning question: Even though these machine learning tools exist for command-line, there is no ready-made webapp that I could install on my server and that would immediately (without custom development) provide machine learning service over HTTP. So: on-topic.

Applied to an hypothetic question "Is there a free wiki SaaS?": Anyone can install Mediawiki on their server within a day and start selling instances. So: off-topic, close and tell asker to look for Mediawiki hosting.

Comment: Ain't this yes/no thing exactly contrary to [this answer](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/683/1935)?

Comment: @ThomasWeller: They do not seem to contradict. Please give an example question that would reveal the contradiction you are talking about. Thanks :-)

Comment: Because the criteria question you defined is: "Is the ... software ... available ... for on-premise installation?" Yes --> then it's on-premise, not hosting. No --> then it's not on-premise, which is external.

Comment: Please note that the question here is only for SaaS questions. When the answer you refer to talks about on-premise, it is for internal use only (self-hosting), not for building a SaaS.

Comment: Now I understand it even less