# Why are users telling me my question isn't on-topic when I've already shown it is?

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question

[A site to upload my code projects to](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/37349/site-to-host-my-personal-code-projects?noredirect=1#comment54454_37349)

I've asked a question ostensibly on topic, and have provided at least three references from this very Meta site to demonstrate this in the comments - the general reasoning being that the site is a web app, and as per the links provided, web apps are on topic for Software Recommendations, because they are essentially software online. A site like the one I've described is definitely a *web app* as opposed to a *website*, because it's function-based rather than content-based. Why, then, am I still being questioned for it?

**Note: before formulating a response to any of this, *please* visit the afore-mentioned answers linked to in the comments of my original question, and reproduced here:**

[Are web service recommendations off-topic?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44/are-web-service-recommendations-off-topic/45#45)

[Can I ask for recommended websites?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191/can-i-ask-for-recommended-websites/219#219)

[From WebApps: Website recommendations](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3930/website-recommendations/3944#3944)

Comment: It would be better to include the "afore-mentioned links provided in the comments" in your question here, because comments can/will get deleted, after which this Meta discussion wouldn’t be of any value anymore.

Comment: Fair point, I'll do that now.

Comment: Out of curiosity, though, why would comments be deleted? Is this common practice to do on SE sites?

Comment: I’d say yes; comments are typically understood to be temporary -- ask for clarification or similar, edit the post, clean up the comments. There are exceptions, of course (e.g., a comment warning that something is dangerous/wrong/etc.). But in your case, the comments discussing if the question is on-topic should be deleted after a decision is made; they wouldn’t be relevant anymore.

Comment: Ah, that's fair enough. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4):

- It is a web service request, and good web service requests are on topic.
- It is not a "website" (as defined on this meta), I agree.
- meta.webapps.stackexchange.com does not have any power here, but anyway it just restates what your first two meta links explain.

For me, the real problem with your question is that it is **too broad**.

I can easily think of 10 webapps that fit your requirements (Github, Bitbucket, Sourceforge, Tigris, Savannah, Launchpad, Codeplex, Alioth, etc) and I am sure I can find dozens of others within a minute.

The question would be less broad if you made the two optional requirements into "must" requirements. But then for the first one, please remove the "CodePen" mention and explain what it must do, and state what technologies must be supported by that feature.